# How to handle a QuotaExceededError or an IO error

Tags: indexeddb

[This paragraph](https://w3c.github.io/IndexedDB/#transaction-lifetime) states:

> A transaction can fail for reasons not tied to a particular request.
>   For example due to IO errors when committing the transaction, or due
>   to running into a quota limit where the implementation can’t tie
>   exceeding the quota to a partcular request. In this case the
>   implementation must run the steps to abort a transaction using the
>   transaction as transaction and the appropriate error type as error.
>   For example if quota was exceeded then a "QuotaExceededError"
>   DOMException should be used as error, and if an IO error happened, an
>   "UnknownError" DOMException should be used as error.

Q: Can you write a code example of this? I'm not sure if they're talking about wrapping a transaction in a try/catch block or using the onerror handler. I'm not sure when they say a "DOMException should be used" if they mean I should do something or that JavaScript is returning something.

Answer (score 0):

This is an instruction to the people that implement the indexedDB code (generally in C or C++) within the browser. It is not directed at you. Some developers do however use those instructions as a way to gain insight into how to use the API.

Certain idb javascript calls can definitely throw exceptions. This is quite different than an error such as the property `request.error` that is set after the occurrence of some error.

Generally, you will not need to catch exceptions. You will only need to check for errors by listening for error events as exclusive alternatives to success events. In other words, for each request, listen for both the error event and the success event, one or the other will always fire, and react appropriately. You only need to catch exceptions if there are actual errors in your code, or more systematic errors like calling `transactionVariable.objectStore('store-that-does-not-exist')`, which if you wrote the app correctly should never happen.